# Create fail2ban filter for custom log

Tags: fail2ban

on my website I use monolog, for example to record failed logins in a log. The entries then look like this:

```
2020-09-25T09:24:22.833648+02:00] Log.ERROR: Failed login attempt, data used:  {"username":"sadf","password":"asdf","IP":"145.255.48.253","Proxy-IP":""} []
```

Now I would like to write a filter for Fail2Ban. The following is what I currently have in mind:

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^Log.ERROR: Failed login attempt, data used:.+$
```

But how can I get the IP or the Proxy-IP when one is set?
Thanks

Comment: You need to log the real IP of the user from the application, fail2ban cannot get this for you. If using Cloudflare for example, there is a HTTP header sent for this, so you log that.